# Angular Impulse in a non-inertial frame

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque

Is $\frac{dL}{dt} = \Gamma$ true in a non-inertial frame?

My book states that it is not. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: In non-inertial frames you can have fictitious forces which can produce torque.

Comment: But if you include those fictitious forces in your analysis, this relationship is valid as is all of Newtonian dynamics.

Comment: Then why is it given invalid then? Does the question expect us not to include the pseudo forces?

Comment: @Ben51 I agree but my hope was that the book was somehow splitting the contributions in order to justify the statement. Which book is it?

Comment: Maybe it's in the context of geophysical fluid dynamics, where motion is constrained to the 2D surface of a sphere, and motions are often analyzed as though they were occuring on a flat, rotating plane instead of a sphere.